# How to list only version tags with git-log?

Tags: git, grep, git-log

I want to create a (latex) table of tags and theirs messages straight out of git, therefor I need to get all tags that match a pattern like:

```
/^v([0-9]|\.)*/
```

or so.

How to do this? My attempt:

```
git log --all --tags --grep="^v([0-9]|\.)*" --pretty=format:"%d & %s & %b"
```

fails and returns nothing (tested on the linux kernel source tree).

Comment: --grep applies to content not names.  What's wrong with a list|filter|process pipe? `git for-each-ref refs/tags | grep  $'\t''refs/tags/v[0-9.]*$'`, seasoned to taste.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ git for-each-ref --format='%(objectname)' \
    'refs/tags/v.*' 'refs/tags/v[0-9]*' | \
    xargs -n 1 git log -1 --pretty=format:"%d & %s & %b"
```

Comment: That's really close, thanks. Now, I just want the version tag (this script also gives me `remote/master` and so on. And `%s` and `%b` seem wrong, as I want the tag message, not the underlying commit message. Can you modify it?