# How can I use `git tag --list` with information from `git log --tags`

Tags: windows, git

I wanted to display the history of all my tags. Using git `git tag --list` I only see e.g. v1.0.0 but nothing about the underlying commit, the tag message and the date. Then I thought I could use `git log --tags` but this adds all tags to the commit history (if I understand correctly) and the list is huge (including all commits and tags). How can I get a list of tags only - something like
* v1.0.0, 873bf3b, Christoph Strauss, 2016-04-20, My first tag
...

**Edit:**

- I am working on windows.
- From the first link: `git rev-list -n 1 $TAG` or `git rev-list -n 1 %TAG%` returns TAG unknown
- From the second link: `git for-each-ref --format='%(objectname)' 'refs/tags/v.*' 'refs/tags/v[0-9]*' | xargs -n 1 git log -1 --pretty=format:"%d & %s & %b"`
  returns xargs unknown, I checked that that the part before worked (with no output)

What am I doing wrong? Unfortunately, I am quite new to git, so any explanation would be higly appreciated! It seems, both answers should be close to what I need but I have no clue what's wrong in my case...

Comment: Did you look a this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862423/how-to-tell-which-commit-a-tag-points-to-in-git

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19850235/6309 should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most answers tend to assume that you have a decent OS (i.e., Linux/BSD/MacOS, but not Windows ... or that if you *do* have Windows you have some sort of decent command line environment for it, so that you can at least work as if you were on a Unix-ish box).  Hence all the commands that pipe into xargs, use awk, and so on.  (These tools *are* available for Windows, I believe, but I do my best to avoid Windows.)

It looks, however, like you are looking to get `git log` output for commits that are tagged, and *only* for those commits.  If so, you are in luck, because git can do this without any outside program assistance.

The command you need is:

```
git log --no-walk --tags
```

(add additional `--format=...` or `--pretty=format:...` as desired).  The `--tags` argument tells `git log` to use all the tags in `refs/tags/` as starting points to show, and the `--no-walk` tells `git log` not to walk the commit graph.

Normally, `git log` starts at `HEAD` or at the specified commit(s), then walks the graph to find all commits reachable from the starting point(s) you specified.  It then sorts all those commits into some sorted order, and displays all of them.  The `--no-walk` flag stops the graph walking (but not the sorting, and there is no `--do-not-sort-at-all` option so you are stuck with, at best, controlling which sort is to be done; see [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html) for details.)

Comment: That answers my questions. I just had a look at the documentation and it seems, that I have to get the annotation like v1.0.0 from somewhere else - e.g. from `git tag`. Correct? My output looks like the following:  
`873bf3b, Christoph Strauss, 2016-04-20, My first tag`

Comment: If you add `--decorate` and/or use the `%d` directive, git will add the tags as decorations (though you will also get branch names, which you might need to clean out).